# Potential Memory Leak in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, memory-leaks

So I just made an app that loads a map with some markers on it. The app has a navigation controller that segue from the main screen to the map and back. While running the app on my phone and simulator i noticed that if i went back and forth between the home screen and the map, the amount of memory that the app was using just kept growing indefinitely. Is there way to assist in the process of memory management (i know the system uses ARC)? Im using the google maps sdk btw.

Thanks!

Comment: See WWDC 2013 video [Fixing Memory Issues](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/?include=410#410) or WWDC 2012 video [iOS App Performance: Memory](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=242). They describe categories of memory issues and illustrate how to use Instruments to identify them. In answer to your question, could be strong reference cycle that's preventing stuff from getting released, some other leak, abandoned memory, or ill-designed cache. It's impossible to say on the basis of what you've shared thus far.

Comment: Are you using a segue to go back to the main screen? If so, that's your problem.

Comment: I am just unwinding the segue (via back button on UINavBar)

Answer (score 0):

Does it cause the app to run out of memory and crash?

Or is it using a ton of memory, receiving a memory warning, and dumping said memory?

So, unless it is causing crashes, it may be behaving correctly.

Comment: It might be behaving correctly, but unlikely, and certainly not something that someone should take on faith. It's irresponsible for an app to randomly consume memory until it runs out; if nothing else you're probably unnecessarily jettisoning other apps. It is laudable that CoderNinja is trying to understand why the app is consuming memory. IMHO, the only issues that fall into the "don't sweat it" category are those _de mimimis_ leaks of (literally) just a few hundred bytes that some standard UIKit controls can cause. But anything sizable should be analyzed in Instruments and tracked down.

Comment: @Rob I mostly agree, which is why I specifically called out the *is it crashing* case.   What I don't agree with is that it is bad behavior for an app to cache to the point of receiving a memory warning, purging said cache, then moving on.  That is well within the design parameters of the system and one of the goals.   Bad for an active background app to do this, certainly, but the current application is free to consume as much resources as it wants to give the user the best experience.  With that said, **optimization is absolutely critical** as is understanding what is going on!

Comment: We'll just agree to disagree on the merits of the "the use memory until you get warning" design approach. Those WWDC videos talk about how failure to mitigate high-water marks can result in (a) the diminished multitasking UX if background apps are routinely evicted; (b) greater heap fragmentation; and (c) you're technically not guaranteed to receive memory warnings. Regardless, seems we're agreed on the broader point: I was just afraid that your answer could be interpreted as "hey, if it doesn't crash, then don't worry", but it doesn't sound like that's what you were trying to say at all.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has extensive and well-documented support for diagnosing these kinds of problems. See ["Locating Memory Issues in Your App"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/MemoryManagementforYouriOSApp/MemoryManagementforYouriOSApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652-CH11-SW1).

Answer (score 0):

Check your codes where using NSThreads and GCD blocks. If there are some places you create plenty of threads, it is recommended to add a autoreleasepool  block.

Memory may leak in these situation:

1. If you are writing a program that is not based on a UI framework, such as a command-line tool.
2. If you write a loop that creates many temporary objects.
3. If you spawn a secondary thread.

For reference: [Using Autorelease Pool Blocks](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/memorymgmt/articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html)

Comment: Yes, if you're manually creating your own threads, then, sure you need to create autorelease pools, but otherwise `@autoreleasepool` is unlikely to be fruitful in resolving memory issues like those described by OP. Pools don't change what is and what is not deallocated, but merely provides a little control over the timing of those deallocations.

Comment: I dont (think) i am creating any threads? At least not explicitly